# How to get the data after we Navigate to another page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to get the data after we post the new data. Now I need to reopen the app to get the inserted data. Like the image, I show below. At **home page,** the details get from the response JSON. **Home page** have a button go to **add data page**. After I click the button to go to **add data page** then after adding data which is **email, username** I go back to my homepage using Navigator.of(context).pop();. The problem is the data did not update, I need to reopen the app to see the newly inserted data.

[image]

Here is my homepage code:

```
Future getDetails() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var decodedData = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      email= decodedData['email'];
      username= decodedData['username'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home page'),
      ),
       body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
         children: <Widget> [
          new Row(
            children: [
             Text('  Name: '+ username, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
            Text('  Email : '+ email, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
          ]
          ),
          new Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 350, 
                child: OutlineButton(
                  child: Text('ADD DATA'),
                  onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage()));},
                )
              )
            ]
          ),
          ]
          ),
       )
    );
  }
```

Here is my add data page code:

```
Future<void> addDetails() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    http.Response response = await http.post(url, 
      body: {
        'username': usernameController.text,
        'email': emailController.text,
      }
    );
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to change your [Navigator#push](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) to `await` on the result from [Navigator#pop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) method. [Navigator#pop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) has a signature with another parameter, which will be accepted on the home page. You can try something like this in your home page.

```
new Row(
   children: [
     SizedBox(
         width: 350, 
         child: OutlineButton(
            child: Text('ADD DATA'),
            onPressed: () async {
              final List<String> pageResult = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage()));

              setState(() {
                email = pageResult[0];
                userName = pageResult[1];
              });
          },
        )
      )
   ]
);
```

And in your other page do this in the pop section:

```
setState(() {
  loading = false; //This is a bug in your code
  Navigator.pop(context, [emailController.text, userNameController.text]);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just edit my question adding username also. If adding username need to write like this   Navigator.pop(context, usernameController.text. emailController.text);?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can pass an array of results besides the context. And set the value. Please accept and upvote the answer if it helps you. Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the code to your navigator pop call? Did you pass an array as the second parameter?

Comment: after I flutter tun again can already. Thank you for your help

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that you need to Initialize the arguments to Map() when set your routes in MaterialApp

Answer (score 1):

Call this inside `initState()` function in your homepage:

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
   getDetails();
  });`

Edit: Replace the push with the following

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage())).then((_){getDetails();});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I try already but did not change. It still needs to reopen the app to get the latest details

Comment: I get error about 'data != null' : A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

Comment: initialize the Strings or handle the null value inside the Text widget like the following:
username ?? ''

Answer (score 0):

You can return a result from the popped route to the `HomePage`:

inside the add data page:

```
setState(() {
      loading = true;
      Navigator.pop(context,email);
    });
```

inside `HomePage`:

```
OutlineButton(
      child: Text('ADD DATA'),
      onPressed: () async {
        final String returnedEmail = await Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage()));
        setState(()=>email = returnedEmail);
      },
    );
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just edit my question adding username also. I have try your answer it cannot work

Comment: @dipgirl it does not work not because it didn't solve the problem in your question, but because you have a typo in your code: you are making loading true always

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to solve your problem:

## 1. Identify your `HomePage` using a `GlobalKey`

You will have to create in a separate file (eg. `keys.dart`) a `GlobalKey` which will identify your `HomePage` widget. This will make the `HomePageState` class public.

```dart
// In the keys.dart file
final GlobalKey<HomePageState> homePageKey = GlobalKey();
```

Once the key is created, use it on `AddDataPage` like this:

```dart
// Import your keys.dart file, and when Calling your HomePage in the build() method, specify the key
HomePage(
  key: homePageKey,
  ...
)
```

## 2. Use the key to refresh your `HomePage` -when needed-

Now in your addDetails() method you can use your `GlobalKey` to refresh the `HomePage`:

```dart
Future<void> addDetails() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    http.Response response = await http.post(url, 
      body: {
        'email': emailController.text,
      }
    );

    // Make this setState callback async, and refresh your HomePage
    setState(() async {
      loading = false;
      await homePageKey.currentState.getDetails();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });

    // Or you can also invert things (here the home page will be shown before refresh, useful if the getDetails() method show a kind of progress bar)
    // setState(() async {
    //   loading = false;
    //   await Navigator.pop(context);
    //   homePageKey.currentState.getDetails();
    // });

}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: In my homepage.dart, I already have GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

Comment: This one cannot be used for the `HomePage` widget, since this key reference a `PaginatorState` (which I think it's not the state class of your `HomePage` widget). You have to create a `GlobalKey` which reference a `HomePageState` to use it with a `HomePage` widget

Answer (score 0):

1. Push navigation

```
new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 5),
                () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignScreen()),
        ));
```

2. Route Navigation

```
onTap: 
        () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SignInScreen()),
```